# Start and stop openconnect using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to achieve the following:

- `./vpnconnect.sh start` should establish a VPN connection to a server.
- `./vpnconnect.sh stop` should terminate the VPN connection.

Here is the attempted shell script which doesn't work as expected. 
It gives error:

```
~$ ./vpnconnect.sh stop
Stopping VPN connection:
./vpnconnect.sh: 22: ./vpnconnect.sh: root: not found
./vpnconnect.sh: 26: ./vpnconnect.sh: 14128: not found
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
#
#

PIDOCN=""
VAR2=""

# Start the VPN
start() {
         echo "Starting VPN Connection"
         eval $(echo 'TestVpn&!' | sudo openconnect -q -b --no-cert-check 127.0.0.1 -u myUser --passwd-on-stdin)
        success $"VPN Connection established"
}

# Stop the VPN
stop() {
        echo  "Stopping VPN connection:"
        VAR2=eval $(sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect)
        echo $VAR2
        eval $(sudo kill -9 $VAR2)

        PIDOCN=eval $(pidof openconnect)
        echo $PIDOCN
        eval $(sudo kill -9 $PIDOCN)
}

### main logic ###
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status openconnect
        ;;
  restart|reload|condrestart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Eww. Are you really targeting an operating system that doesn't have a real process supervision system? Almost everyone has one these days -- Apple has launchd, Ubuntu has upstart (on old versions) or systemd (on new ones), Red Hat has systemd, etc.

Comment: ...using a process supervision system will mean that the OS already knows how to check processes' status, shut them down, restart them, etc., so you just need to describe how to start them. (Oddly enough, back *before* this kind of init script became common, folks just used `/etc/inittab`, which was an early, somewhat rudimentary but perfectly workable process supervision system; we went from that to the mess of everyone having their own init script).

Comment: Also, a process supervision system will know exactly which PIDs are associated with a given daemon, instead of just looking at which PIDs have a similar name, or happen to have the same number (which isn't a reliable indicator: process ID numbers get reused after wraparound takes place!)

Comment: Lots of systems have also [runit](http://smarden.org/runit) or [DJB daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) packages; most [run scripts for those](http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html) are not more than one or two lines, since they only need to deal with startup, not shutdown/restart/status/etc.

Answer (score 6):

The error messages:

```
./vpnconnect.sh: 22: ./vpnconnect.sh: root: not found
./vpnconnect.sh: 26: ./vpnconnect.sh: 14128: not found
```

Come from these lines:

```
VAR2=eval $(sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect)
PIDOCN=eval $(pidof openconnect)
```

These lines are non-sense. The shell takes the output of the `$(...)` sub-shells and tries to execute them as commands, with `VAR2` and `PIDOCN` variables set to "eval". This is definitely not what you wanted.

Probably you're looking for something more like this:

```
stop() {
    echo  "Stopping VPN connection:"
    sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect
    sudo kill -9 $(pidof openconnect)
}
```

Comment: I found that calling the following work as expected.  sudo pkill openconnect

Comment: Sure, that could work too, instead of `sudo kill -9 $(pidof openconnect)`. (I didn't offer it because I couldn't be sure you have the command.)

Comment: Is this the correct way, though? When I do a `pkill openconnect` it leaves my `resolv.conf` modified with the VPN-connection's nameservers and my ip route isn't restored correctly?! Ok, I found it. I observed that Ctrl+C worked properly, therefore just send the same signal i.e. `SIGINT` with `sudo pkill -2 openconnect`.

Comment: If you kill openconnect it seems possibly not to clean up the iptables, as the next time you run it it gives a warning "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" maybe there is a better way to kill it?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `eval`:

```
VAR2=eval $(sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect)
```

Here, `eval` will try to execute the output of `sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect` command.  That's the reason you are getting the errors you are seeing.

Rewrite it as:

```
VAR2=$(sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect)
```

Which will simply assign the output of the `sudo` command pipeline to `VAR2` variable.  However, you can't use `VAR2` as an argument to `kill` because it contains other tokens like username along with the PID.

In other places where you are doing `eval $(command)`, all you need is `command`.

You could use `pkill openconnect` to kill any existing `openconnect` processes instead of finding out the PID and issuing a `kill` against it. `pgrep` and `pkill` are quite handy for start/stop/restart script like yours.

Comment: sudo pkill openconnect worked as expected. The other suggestion VAR2=$(sudo ps -aef | grep openconnect) didn't work. It throws error Stopping VPN connection:
./vpnconnect.sh: 22: ./vpnconnect.sh: root: not found

./vpnconnect.sh: 26: ./vpnconnect.sh: 14128: not found

Comment: If you use `pgrep` and `pkill`, you don't need to find the PID with `ps` and `grep`.